# SAS "successfully assigned from logical server" vs "successfully assigned as follows"

Tags: sas

As I was looking through a log file from 
D:\SAS\XXX\Lev1\SASMain\BatchServer\Logs

I saw these two lines

```
NOTE: Libref TESTLIB successfully assigned from logical server.

NOTE: Libref TESTLIB was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        XXXX 
      Physical Name: XX.XXX.XXX.XX
```

What is the difference between or meaning behind these two lines?

Answer (score 4):

The first line tells you that the library has been assigned as a pre-assigned library from metadata. If you look at SAS Management Console>Data Library Manager>TESTLIB>properties>Options>Advanced Options>"Library is Pre-Assigned". If this checbox is ticked, you will see the first line, given that the user has "Read Metadata" permissions on the library.
The second line comes if the library is explicitly assigned in the code. DI Studio will create libname statements in the code if the library is not pre-assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you found the two lines right next to each other:

- The first line is telling you that SAS encountered no problems trying to assign the libref TESTLIB. If you tried to assign a libref to a non-existent folder / server, or you didn't have the necessary access (etc...) you'd get an error message instead of this line.
- The second line is telling you a bit more about the libref that was assigned. In your case this includes the IP address of the server and SAS libname engine used. Depending on the value of `XXXX`, it's possible that in this case you're connecting to a different DBMS.